# Entire function with limited growth

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Let $M(r) = max_{|z| = r}f(z)$. I need to prove that if $\log M(r) = o(\sqrt{r})$ then such function is unlimited on real line or constant. I have only managed to found an example of such function $f(z) = z$. I have no idea how to approach this problem. Will be glad for any help.

Comment: This looks like a Phragmén-Lindelöf type argument to me.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One version of Lindelof Theorem claims that if $|g(iy)| \le M, |g(z)| \le C_ae^{aR},\Re z \ge 0, |z| \le R$ where $|a| < \frac{\pi}{2}$ then $|g(z)| \le M^{c(z)}, c(z)=\frac{a \Re z}{\cos a}, \Re z \ge 0$;

(this is classic and follows by first proving a boundness result for an angle less than $\pi$ when we are given bounds on the boundary of the angle and then applying this to $e^{-bz/\cos a}g(z)$ in the first and fourth quadrants respectively with $b >a, b \to a$)

In particular, if the result above holds with $a \to 0, a>0$ it follows that $|g(z)| \le M$ in the right half plane $\Re z \ge 0$

Now assuming $f$ as in the OP (that is called $f$ has order at most $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ or in other words, $f$ has order strictly less than $1/2$ or it has order $1/2$ but it is of minimal type) is bounded on the real line (note that it is enough to assume boundness on either positive or negative half-line) we will show that $f$ is constant.

Assume boundness on say the negative real half line we apply the above with $g(z)=f(z^2)$ which is even and satisfies $|g(iy)| \le M$ (while if $f$ bounded on the positive reals we just take $g(z)=f(-z^2)$) and the hypothesis in the OP imply that $|g(z)| \le C_ae^{aR},\Re z \ge 0, |z| \le R$ for arbitrary $a>0$ because $\log M_f(R) = o(\sqrt{R})$ is clearly equivalent to $\log M_g(R) = o(R)$

By the Lindelof Theorem quoted, it follows that $g$ is bounded in the right half-plane and since $g$ is even it follows that $g$ is bounded in the plane, hence it is constant and so is $f$. Done!

A non-trivial example of such an $f$ is $\Pi_{n \ne 0}(1-z/n^3)$ which has order $1/3$ by simple results in the theory of entire functions (number of zeroes in a disc of radius $R$ is ~ $R^{1/3}$ and that being a non-integral power immediately implies that the function has order $1/3$)

Edit later - to clarify a bit what happens (per comments), the idea is that the lower the order of growth of an entire nonconstant function, the more constrained its boundness at infinity properties are which may seem a bit unintuitive (as lower order of growth means the function grows slower after all) but it should become intuitive if we think of the order of growth in terms of its non-exceptional values in the Picard sense (so all complex numbers but at most one) as the lower the order, the "fewer" (density per area wise as they ar infinitely many otherwise except for polynomials) solutions $f(z)=a$ has so it means that $f$ must spread out faster

Polynomials go to infinity; functions of order up to $(1/2,0)$ cannot be bounded on any ray (though $\infty$ is still an essential singularity so all but at most one values are  $f(z_n), |z_n| \to \infty$, functions of order up to $(1,0)$ cannot be bounded on any line, up to order $(2,0)$ cannot be bounded on two perpendicular lines at the same time, etc; in infinite order, there are entire nonconstant functions that are bounded on every line through $0$ (though of course non-uniformly by Liouville); examples like $\cos \sqrt z$ of order $1/2$ and finite non zero type which is bounded on the positive reals, $\cos z$, positive type order $1$ bounded on the reals, $\cos z^2$ positive type order $2$ bounded on both the real and imaginary axis show that these types of results (that come under Phragmen-Lindelof or just Lindelof theorems) are sharp.

Comment: Am i understand correctly that it's like Lindelof Theorem for the sector where sector is pushed to extreme: $2\pi$, so positive real ray will be it's boundary?

Comment: yes for $f$ - the condition of growth of order at most $(1/2,0)$ implies indeed that by the manipulations above we can get a Lindelof like result assuming boundness on any ray, so if you want pushing the sector to the full $2\pi$ angle; the condition is sharp as $f(z)=\cos \sqrt z$ has order $1/2$ but finite non zero type and it is obviously bounded on the positive real axis (on the negative real axis it is unbounded though)

Comment: Sorry for making you wait so long. I'm trying to understand why we got it so easy if Phragmen-Lindelof theorem wants function to be bounded for some $a < \pi / 2$. But when we move from $2\pi $ sector to half plane we only have bound for $a = \pi / 2$. At the same time the result sounds believable because we have not the usual bound $M(r) <= .. $ but $M(r) = o( .. )$ And I don't get where this transition had happened.

Comment: Phragmne Lindelof gives a constant bound within an angle up to strictly less than $\pi$ (symmetric opening less than $\pi/2)$; it gives a non-constant bound $M^{c_a(z)}, a>0$ within a half-plane (angle $\pi$ or symmetric opening $\pi/2$) with $c_a(z) \to 0, a \to 0$ on compact sets in $z$ so an estimate $M_g << e^{ar}, a>0$arbitrary gives $g$ bounded in a half-plane by letting $a \to 0$; for $f$ the estimate $M_f << e^{a\sqrt r}$ leads to $g(z)=f(z^2)$ having estimate as above, so $g$ hence $f$ have constant estimate and by evenness it holds in the full plane